# enable_if and conversion operator?

Tags: c++, boost, casting, operator-overloading, enable-if

Any chance to use `enable_if` with a type conversion operator? Seems tricky, since both return type and parameters list are implicit.

Comment: C++0x makes it possible by default arguments: `template<typename T, typename = typename enable_if<Cond>::type> operator T() { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dixit the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html):
*There does not seem to be a way to specify an enabler for a conversion operator. Converting constructors, however, can have enablers as extra default arguments.*

Comment: With C++11 this is no longer the case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100297/how-can-i-use-stdenable-if-in-a-conversion-operator

Answer (score 10):

From the little research I did (and ignoring the c++0x comment from Johannes), my answer is that it depends what you want the `enable_if` for. If you want the conversion operation to `T` to exist or not from the type `T` then it seems that the answer is no, there is no way in C++03 (as Ugo said). But if you need the `enable_if` to change the *behavior* of the operator depending on the type of `T` then yes, there is a workaround which is to call an enabled helper function (called `to<T>` as Matthieu suggested).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include<boost/type_traits/is_class.hpp>

struct B{
    B(const B& other){}
    B(){}
};

struct A{
    template<class T>
    T to(typename boost::enable_if_c<not boost::is_class<T>::value, void*>::type = 0){
        std::clog << "converted to non class" << std::endl;
        return T(0);
    }
    template<class T>
    T to(typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_class<T>::value, void*>::type = 0){
        std::clog << "conveted to class" << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
    template<class T>
    operator T(){
        return to<T>();
    }
};

int main(){
    A a;
    double d = (double)a; // output: "converted to non class"
    B b = (B)(a); // output: "converted to class"
    return 0;
}
```

For the record, I was frustrated with this for several days, until I realized that I wanted `enable_if` not for SFINAE but for compile-time behavior change. You may also find that this is the real reason for your need for `enable_if` also. Just a suggestion.

(Please note that this is an answer for the C++98 era)

Comment: You say it is not possible that the operation "exists or not" depending on type T. However, if you leave one `to()` out, the corresponding cast will fail with a compile time error, which is the desired behavior. Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, I think you are right, but is that the intention behind the question?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your answer, you say "it is not possible in c++03", but then you show how it *is* possible.

Answer (score 2):

While I can understand the theoritecal interest in the question, I personally refrain from using conversion operators as much as possible.

The only one I ever use with consistence is the conversion to a pseudo-boolean (using the Safe Bool idiom), for smart-pointers or proxies, and as noted I use a trick to actually prevent the full boolean semantic...

If I ever want to facilitate conversions, I much prefer something along the line of:

```
template <class T>
T to() const;
```

which does not suffer from the limitations (in term of signature) of the conversion operator and requires explicit invocation, just because it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I have found a way; we use a private, unused class to mark a conversion that shouldn't exist, and we use `boost::mpl::if_` to select whether to produce a conversion to NoConversion, or to the desired type.

```
class A {
    class NoConversion { };
    template<class B> operator typename boost::mpl::if_<Cond, B, NoConversion>::type() const;
}
```