# how can I use std::enable_if in a conversion operator?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, sfinae, enable-if

Basically I want my range type to be implicitly convertible from `Range<const char>` to `Range<const unsigned char>`. std::enable_if seems impossible because the function takes no arguments and has no return. Whats the work around?

Here is basically what I tried:

```
template<typename T>
class Range{
    T* begin_;
    T* end_;
public:
    Range(T* begin,T* end):begin_{begin},end_{end}{}
    template<int N>
    Range(T (&a)[N]):begin_{static_cast<T*>(&a[0])},end_{static_cast<T*>(&a[N-1])}{}
    T* Begin(){return begin_;}
    T* End(){return end_;}
    operator typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,const char>::value,Range<const unsigned char>&>::Type (){
        return *reinterpret_cast<Range<const unsigned char>*>(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: why not using `std::is_same<>` instead of `Loki::IsSameType<>` ??

Comment: I'm programming bare metal on an ARM cortex and it was easier at first to get Loki working, so good point and I changed it ;)

Comment: Do you really need a conversion operator? Or could you live with `operator=` and constructor?

Comment: `std::enable_if` has a member type(def) `type` (small `t`), not `Type`.

Comment: You could use a [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to switch between `Range<const unsigned char>` and `void` for the conversion operator (according to clang++, a conversion operator to `void` is legal and never used). Or you could use specialization of the class template.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make it a template with a dummy parameter that defaults to T - this is to postpone type deduction to the point where the function gets instantiated, otherwise SFINAE [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972368/stdenable-if-to-conditionally-compile-a-member-function). Then you do the check you want in default value of another parameter.

```
template<
    typename U = T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<U,const char>::value >::type
>
operator Range<const unsigned char>() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<Range<const unsigned char>*>(this);
}
```

Note: With C++17 or later, the above can be shortened slightly to:

```
template<typename U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U,const char>>>
operator Range<const unsigned char>() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<Range<const unsigned char>*>(this);
}
```

Comment: @joik thanks for pointing out my error with conflicting conversion operators, I removed it.

Comment: Also note the somewhat unusual "typename = typename ...". It would not work for me if I used a type name.

Comment: @einpoklum Your improvement doesn't work an any major compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/MrxzsPq5a original works on gcc fails  on clang: https://godbolt.org/z/K7639Ejod (do not see result for MSVC - performance issue).

Comment: @MarekR: That's because I deleted the `typename =`, which I shouldn't have. Fixed.

Comment: Yes I've missed that too. Sadly clang has strange complains: https://godbolt.org/z/fTKEnPcTq `error: conversion function converting 'Range<const unsigned char>' to itself will never be used` I wonder why SFINAE didn't kick in for `Range<const unsigned char>`.

Comment: Got version which works on all compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/r3z1GhPPf