# Template specialization and enable_if problems

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enable-if

I am running into a problem regarding the appropriate usage of enable_if and template specialization.

After modifying the example (for confidentiality reasons), here's a comparable example:

> I have function called "less" that checks if 1st arg is less than 2nd
>   arg. Let's say I want to have 2 different kinds of implementations
>   depending  on the type of input - 1 implementation for integer and
>   another for double.

The code that I have so far looks like this -

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class T,
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
     bool less(T a, T b) {
  // ....
}

template <class T,
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
     bool less(T a, T b) {
  // ....
}

int main() {
    float a;
    float b;
    less(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code does not compile because - It says that I am re-defining the less method.

Errors are:

```
Z.cpp:15:19: error: template parameter redefines default argument
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>

                  ^
Z.cpp:9:19: note: previous default template argument defined here
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type>
                  ^

Z.cpp:16:11: error: redefinition of 'less'
     bool less(T a, T b) {
          ^

Z.cpp:10:11: note: previous definition is here
     bool less(T a, T b) {
          ^

Z.cpp:23:5: error: no matching function for call to 'less'
    less(a,b);
    ^~~~

Z.cpp:15:43: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if'
      [with T = float]
          class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
                                          ^
3 errors generated.
```

Can someone point out what's the mistake here?

Comment: essentially you are not using `enable_if` correctly because of how you invoke the return type.

Comment: Quick solution is to add an ellipsis parameter `...` to either one of the templates so that they are considered distinct overloads.

Comment: Or change the signature(s) to `template <class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Default template arguments are not part of the signature of a function template. So in your example you have two identical overloads of `less`, which is illegal. clang complains about the redefinition of the default argument (which is also illegal according to §14.1/12 [temp.param]), while gcc produces the following error message:

> error: redefinition of '`template<class T, class> bool less(T, T)`'

To fix the error move the `enable_if` expression from default argument to a dummy template parameter

```
template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, int>::type* = nullptr>
     bool less(T a, T b) {
  // ....
}

template <class T,
          typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type* = nullptr>
     bool less(T a, T b) {
  // ....
}
```

---

Another option is to use `enable_if` in the return type, though I feel this is harder to read.

```
template <class T>
      typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type 
      less(T a, T b) {
  // ....
}

template <class T>
     typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type 
     less(T a, T b) {
  // ....
}
```

Comment: Technically, the first set of code is ill-formed according to the standard, because `void *` isn't a valid type for a template non-type parameter. In practice, no compiler that I know of actually cares. The fix is trivial, though.

Comment: I changed it to be a function parameter and that works now