# Implementing/using EnableIf and DisableIf

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

I'm trying to get a grasp of C++ metaprogramming, and how to make it a bit less painful, at least visually. I've come across this thread:

http://loungecpp.wikidot.com/tips-and-tricks:enable-if-for-c-11

Suggesting a more pleasent-to-read version of `std::enable_if`. Here's the code:

```
template <typename T>
using Invoke = typename T::type;

template <typename Condition>
using EnableIf = Invoke<std::enable_if<Condition::value>>;

// Left as an exercise to the reader on the original page - I hope I got it right
template <typename Condition>
using DisableIf = Invoke<std::enable_if<!Condition::value>>;
```

When I try to use them, however, it seems that the non-integral version behaves just like the integral one, i.e. the DisableIf behaves like an EnableIf. Code:

```
template <typename T, typename = EnableIf<std::is_integral<T>> >
void foo(const T& t) { std::cout << t << " is integral!"; }

template <typename T, typename = DisableIf<std::is_integral<T>> >
void foo(const T& t) { std::cout << t << " is_ not_ integral!"; }

int main() {
    foo(123); foo(456.0);
}
```

Compiler output (`g++ 5.1.1 --std=c++14`):

```
g.cpp:21:6: error: redefinition of ‘template<class T, class> void foo(const T&)’
 void foo(const T& t) { std::cout << t << " is_ not_ integral!"; }
      ^
g.cpp:18:6: note: ‘template<class T, class> void foo(const T&)’ previously declared here
 void foo(const T& t) { std::cout << t << " is integral!"; }
      ^
g.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
g.cpp:24:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(double)’
     foo(123); foo(456.0);
                        ^
g.cpp:18:6: note: candidate: template<class T, class> void foo(const T&)
 void foo(const T& t) { std::cout << t << " is integral!"; }
      ^
g.cpp:18:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Is it an error with my `DisableIf` definition, or is something else the matter?

Comment: There is a also [enable_if_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)

Comment: Note: enable_if_t (since C++14)

Comment: Another dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29502052/241631

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Yes, I know, but `EnableIf` is even nicer than that, as you don't have to save `::value`...