# Is there a C++14 alternative to explicit(expr) introduced in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++20, implicit-conversion, template-meta-programming

**TL;DR**: I am looking for a C++14 equivalent of the following C++20 MWE:

```cpp
template<int sz>
struct bits {
  int v; // note explicit(expr) below
  explicit(sz > 1) operator bool() const { return bool(v); }
};

int main() {
  bool c = bits<1>{1}; // Should work
  bool d = bits<3>{1}; // Should fail
}
```

**Context:**

We have a C++ class `bits<sz>` representing bitvectors of length `sz`.  Conversion to `bool` used to be implicit for all `sz`, but this proved to be error-prone, so we changed `operator bool()` to be explicit.

However, `1-bit` bitvectors are (in our context) almost-completely equivalent to Booleans, so it would be desirable for `operator bool()` to be implicit when `sz == 1`.

This can be achieved with `explicit(sz > 1)` in [C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), but we are targeting C++14.

I tried to overload the operator for `sz == 1`, but it seems that the `explicit` qualifier applies to it as well: the following does not work.

```cpp
template<int sz>
struct bits {
  int v;
  explicit operator bool() const { return bool(v); }
};

template<> bits<1>::operator bool() const {
  return bool(v);
}

int main() {
  bool c = bits<1>{1}; // Fails: "No viable conversion"
}
```

Hence the question: **How can I specify in C++14 that `operator bool()` should be explicit only for `sz > 1`?**

I'm including some background below for curious readers.

**Background**:

This problem came up in the context of an embedded domain-specific language in C++.  One of the business requirements is that `operator==` returns a `bit<1>`, not a `bool`.  This is working smoothly with GNU's libstdc++, but we're running into trouble with that requirement on macOS because libstdc++ there implements `operator==` on `std::array` using the version of `std::equal` that takes a predicate, and implements that predicate using a struct whose `operator()` returns `bool` with body `a == b` (which in our case returns a `bits<1>`, causing a conversion error).

To make it concrete for curious readers, the following program compiles fine on GNU, but not on macOS, because of the way `operator==` on `std::array` is implemented:

```cpp
#include <array>

struct S { explicit operator bool() const { return true; } };

struct T {};
S operator==(T, T) { return S(); }

int main() {
  std::array<T, 1> arr = { T() };
  return arr == arr;
}
```

That's because deep down in the implementation of `==` on arrays GNU libstdc++ has a test `if (!(*it1 == *it2))`, which invokes the `explicit operator bool()` on `S` without trouble, where as on macOS the library uses `if (!__pred(*it1, *it2))` with `__pred` roughly equivalent to `bool __pred(S a, S b) { return a == b; }`, which doesn't typecheck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27433093/enable-conversion-operator-using-sfinae) SFINAE the conversion operator:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<int sz>
struct bits {
  int v;
  explicit operator bool() const { return bool(v); }

  template <int S = sz>
  operator std::enable_if_t<S == 1, bool> () const { return bool(v);}
};
```

Check it [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KG3q4s15e)

```
int main()
{
  bool c1 = bits<1>{1};                    // Ok
  bool c2 = bits<3>{1};                    // error cannot convert
  bool c3 = static_cast<bool>(bits<3>{1}); // OK
}
```