# enable_if on explicit templated cast operator gives "invalid static_cast"

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, sfinae, enable-if

I'm attempting to do a templated explicit cast operator.  I found that notationally, you actually can put an expression with type traits and `std::enable_if` in the operator's "name" slot.  But the following test doesn't give the desired behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class WillCast {
public:
    explicit operator int () {
       return 1020;
    }
};

class WontCast {
public:
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<T, int>::value, int
    >::type toInteger()
    {
       return 1324;
    }

    template <typename T>
    explicit operator typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<T, int>::value, int
    >::type ()
    {
       return 304;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(WillCast{}) << "\n";   // ok
    std::cout << WontCast{}.toInteger<int>() << "\n";    // ok
    /* std::cout << static_cast<int>(WontCast{}); */     // error 
};
```

The error coming back from gcc 4.8.2 is:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:27:45: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘WontCast’ to type ‘int’
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(WontCast{});
```

If what I'm trying to do were not possible, I wouldn't be surprised.  But it seems to think the syntax is all right, it's just not seeming to behave consistently between the "nearby" behaviors seen by `WontCast::toInteger()` and `WillCast::operator int()`.

*(This is a reduced example, of course my desired `enable_if` is trickier.)*

---

**UPDATE** - "Sidebar intelligence(tm)" has thrown up [How can I use std::enable_if in a conversion operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100297/how-can-i-use-stdenable-if-in-a-conversion-operator?rq=1) which I didn't find through "BeforeYouAsked intelligence(tm)".  I will look and see if it helps.  Well, the solution used there doesn't seem to apply, because WontCast isn't a templated class.  So not helping here.

Comment: What about [specialization](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f860354bf54a365)?

Comment: @remyabel That does work for that specific case, but if that specific case were what I was looking for I could just go with WillCast and say "int".  I'm looking for something that does pattern matching and produces a lot of cast operators... but only under the right cases.

Comment: How about [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/104248a4014efff6)? It uses the same trick as the link you have in your question.

Comment: @HostileFork Cool question - I didn't even realize this was possible until I started trying things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move the `enable_if` part into the template, this works:

```
template <typename T,
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value>::type
          >
explicit operator T()
{
    return 304;
}
```

Given that:

```
int i = static_cast<int>(WontCast{}); // ok
double d = static_cast<double>(WontCast{}); // invalid static_cast
```