# SFINAE for cast operator

Tags: c++, gcc, sfinae, enable-if, typecast-operator

I have a class, which wraps an enum and provides string conversion for it. Now I introduced the template parameter 'fastStringConvert' which controls how the conversion made using SFINAE (found here: [how can I use std::enable_if in a conversion operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100297/how-can-i-use-stdenable-if-in-a-conversion-operator)). The code compiles under MSVC, but fails under GCC and Clang.

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
```

What could be the problem and how should I change the code?

The relevant parts of the code below or here: http://rextester.com/SYC74124

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <
    class SubClass, 
    typename EnumType, 
    bool fastStringConvert = true
>
class SmartEnum
{
public:
    template <
        typename SFINAEPostponer = EnumType,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<fastStringConvert, void>::type
    >
    explicit operator const std::string&() const 
    {
        auto name = SubClass::names().find((int)value);
        if (name != SubClass::names().end())
        {
            return name->second;
        }
        else
        {
            static const std::string na("n.a.");
            return na;
        }
    }

    template <
        typename SFINAEPostponer = EnumType,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<!fastStringConvert, void>::type
    >
    explicit operator const std::string() const
    {
        auto name = SubClass::names().find((int)value);
        if (name != SubClass::names().end()) return name->second;
        else return std::to_string((int)value);
    }

protected:
    typedef const std::map<int, std::string> Names;
    EnumType value;
};


enum class Foo_type : int { a, b, c }; 

struct Foo : SmartEnum<Foo, Foo_type, true>
{ 
    typedef SmartEnum<Foo, Foo_type, true> Base; 

    static const Base::Names &names() 
    { 
        static const Base::Names names = { { 0, "a" }, { 1, "b" }, { 2,"c" }}; 
        return names; 
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use template argument from the method, else you have a hard error, something like:

```
template <
    typename SFINAEPostponer = EnumType,
    bool Cond = !fastStringConvert,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<Cond, void>::type
>
explicit operator const std::string() const
```

BTW, better to use `enable_if` as type instead of default value (to allow disable part):

```
template <
    typename SFINAEPostponer = EnumType,
    bool Cond = !fastStringConvert,
    typename std::enable_if<Cond, void>::type* = nullptr
>
explicit operator const std::string() const
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I don't even need the first argument this way.

Comment: Could you explain what is the difference between this two solution?

Comment: @simon you can't overload a function only base on default value of template parameter, just like you can't overload function on base of default value of its parameter.

Comment: I recently watched a video by Stephan T. Lavavej where he recommended to use `typename std::enable_if<Cond, void**>::type = nullptr` because there is nothing that can implicitly convert to `void**`.