# Can I detect which tag dispatch overload is used at compile time?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++03

Say I have a functor that uses tag dispatching to select from multiple implementations of the function, something like this:

```
// base class for all tags, indicating the "default" implementation
struct tag_base { };

// subclasses for tags that might select a different implementation
struct tag1 : tag_base { };
struct tag2 : tag1  { };
struct tag3 : tag2 { };

struct func
{
    void operator()(tag_base) { }
    void operator()(tag3) { }
};
```

In this simple example, therefore, tag types `tag1` and `tag2` would dispatch to the call operator for `func` that takes a `tag_base`, the default implementation. However, `tag3` would instead dispatch to a different implementation. I'm interested in inspecting at compile time whether, for a given function type `func` and two tag types `T` and `U`, whether they would dispatch to the same overload of `func`'s call operator.

Basically, I would like a trait like this (only pseudocode, since this approach does not compile):

```
template <typename Func, typename T, typename U>
struct has_same_tag_overload
{
    enum { value =  (void (Func::*)(T)) &func::operator() ==
                    (void (Func::*)(U)) &func::operator() };
}
```

So in the above example, the following would be true:

- `tag<func, tag_base, tag1>::value == 1`
- `tag<func, tag_base, tag2>::value == 1`
- `tag<func, tag1, tag2>::value == 1`
- `tag<func, tag1, tag3>::value == 0`
- `tag<func, tag2, tag3>::value == 0`

Is this possible? To add to the degree of difficulty, is this possible in C++03?

Comment: @VTT No it doesn’t, for two reasons: 1. you can’t compare pointers of distinct type for equality, and 2. there is no overload of type `void (func::*)(tag1)`, so the trait doesn’t work with inheritance.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I transferred it over here. gcc complains about the cast being invalid; I would like to invoke the trait using T= tag1 and U = tag2, but since the corresponding overload takes tag_base instead, it says the cast is invalid.

Comment: @JasonR Are the functions actually `void`, or is that a simplification for SO? I expect you could do it if you changed the return type to the same as the tag parameter, but I would only know how in C++11 with `decltype` even then.

Comment: @VTT I believe that the checks [here](https://godbolt.org/g/UJdVNT) should all work, except the part where I wrote them with `static_assert`. Checking that the overload exists is only part of that, and we might just be able to assume that and refuse to compile if there’s no relevant overload.

Comment: @DanielH: The functions are not `void`, that was a simplification, but the return types for two different tags are identical in some cases.

Comment: Cat tags inherit only from some base classes or from "lower level" tags as well (e.g. `struct tag4: tag2 {}`)?

Comment: @VTT They can inherit from one another, as in your example.

Comment: It seems that solving this problem would require figuring out exact signature of the function that may be called with a given argument, that is figuring out possible conversion sequences between tags. So this is hardly possible without explicitly supplying list of tags for which overloads exist.

Comment: @VTT Yes, that's what I thought might be the case. You're right, the question eventually simplifies to the problem of, for a given set of arguments, determining what overload of a function would be invoked (while allowing implicit conversions). I think even if I could do so at runtime, I could benefit in my application, but I haven't figured out a way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the tags form a tree hierarchy, and hence can be written as

```
struct tag_base { using base = void; };
struct tag1 : tag_base { using base = tag_base; };
struct tag2 : tag1  { using base = tag1; };
struct tag3 : tag1  { using base = tag1; };
...
// or something like tag4: is_a<tag2> {}; if you don't like typing ...
```

then we could write

```
template<class U>
struct tag_matcher
{
  template<class V, class W = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U,V>::value> >
  operator V();
};

template<typename F, typename T>
std::true_type match_tag_impl( decltype(F{}(tag_matcher<T>()))* );

template<typename F, typename T>
std::false_type match_tag_impl( ... );

template<typename F, typename T>
struct match_tag
{
  using type = std::conditional_t< decltype(match_tag_impl<F,T>(0))::value,
    T, typename match_tag<F, typename T::base>::type >;
};

template<typename F>
struct match_tag<F,void> { using type = void; };

template<typename F, typename T, typename U>
struct has_same_tag_overload:
  std::is_same< typename match_tag<F,T>::type, typename match_tag<F,U>::type > {};
```

the idea is to check all ancestors in order to find the most derived match, then check if the two are the same or not. This is c++11, but you can make it work for c++03 too as far as I can tell.

#### update re C++03:

as mentioned in the comment, the tag_matcher as defined above cannot work in c++03, because we have no default function template parameters there, hence making sfinae enabled conversion operator templates impossible.
That said, we can move the same logic as tag converting constructors:

```
template<class U>
struct tag_matcher{};

// macro just for expository purposes
#define MATCHME(TAG) template<class T> TAG( tag_matcher<T>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,TAG>::value>* = 0 )

struct tag_base { using base = void; MATCHME(tag_base); };
struct tag1 : tag_base { using base = tag_base; MATCHME(tag1); };
// ...
```

Comment: This is a good idea. I think I may be able to make this work; I hadn't considered building any additional metadata into the tag types themselves. I don't see anything these that would preclude a C++03 implementation either. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, after looking at it more, I'm stuck on translating the `std::enable_if_t` on the `tag_matcher` conversion operator to C++03. Default template parameters on functions weren't supported until C++11, so disabling conversion operators via SFINAE [doesn't seem to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076206/enable-if-and-conversion-operator). Do you see any alternate implementation that works around this?

Comment: @jasonr you’re right, missed that. Have you tried adding an equivalent  tag_matcher converting constructor to the tags instead ?

Comment: @jasonr ok, tested myself now and it works for me, see edit

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of doing this would severely complicate the definition of your `func` type. I'm going to use C++14 features here:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Func, typename Tag1, typename Tag2>
using has_same_tag_overload =
    std::is_same<decltype(Func::fn(Tag1{})), decltype(Func::fn(Tag2{}))>;

struct func
{
    static auto fn(tag_base) {
        return [] { std::cout << "tag_base\n"; };
    }
    static auto fn(tag3) {
        return [] { std::cout << "tag3\n"; };
    }

    template <typename Tag>
    void operator()(Tag tag)
    {
        fn(tag)();
    }
};
```

The idea is that you have your `func` struct create the function to call before calling it, having each function be a distinct type. This means that we can simply compare the function type using `std::is_same`.

This is doable in C++03, but the code gets messier. `func` would have to return distinct function object types. Instead of `decltype`, you could possibly use the `sizeof` trick (have each function object type in `func` be of a different size, so that you can just compare the sizes.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something similar, but unfortunately returning `void` was just a simplification for SO. I suppose you could do something like this but add an implicit conversion to the real return type.

Comment: @DanielH handling a return type is extremely easy with this technique: add a return type on the lambdas and the `operator()`